# how to get the token from Microsoft Teams directly when user logs in the teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

I created a bot using Visual Studio 2017 and published it to Azure and uploaded to MS Teams.I need to authenticate the user.I need to get the user specific token when user logs in the MS teams instead of logging in again in the pop up

Comment: All the third party apps need to ask for user consent before getting the access token. Please take a look at [Microsoft Teams authentication flow for bots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/auth-flow-bot).

Comment: so we cannot get the token without sign in auth card/pop up?

Comment: Not for delegated permissions. You can use Application permissions in which your App Id and App Secret is used to get the token. Please take a look at documentation on [Microsoft Graph permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0#microsoft-graph-permissions).

Comment: so for my bot that is deployed in MS Teams,I can access token through Microsoft Graph?

Comment: We have a bot created using Azure Bot framework which has been integrated with MS Teams.
Now in order to authenticate the user, we need to access the token generated when the user logged in to MS Teams.
So far, I have found out that we can get the token generated for the bot deployed in MS Teams using Azure Bot Service where user will have to sign in in
the OAUTH card for the Bot and then the token is generated.
But we are trying to find a solution where we can access the token without the need for the user to log in again after its initial logging into MS teams.

Comment: This is possible only when user Sign in and provides consent that your App could access the specified resources.

Comment: when we log into the MS teams for first time,it must be generating some token on client side,can we access it?

Comment: Your app cannot access the token generated by the teams client when you login